# Pushing matrices to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

Greetings fellow programmers,

https://jsfiddle.net/martin_varbanov/vq5hhzmo/2/

I have this array called arrStack which is meant to be my stack and I want to push some matrices in it. The pop() function works fine but when I try to manipulate an array and push it to the stack, it doesn't seem to work properly, examples:

expected:

```
[

        [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
        [[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]        
]
```

result:

```
[
    [[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
    [[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]

]
```

Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you fix your jsFiddle so we can understand the problem better ?

Comment: I don't have the ability to visualize the matrices into divs, could you just create a new html and js project, copy paste and check your browser dev tools' console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because when you do arrStack.push(arr);, you are not pushing the clone of arr instance but you are pushing a reference.

You can avoid that by converting arr to JSON and parsing it back like below.

```
arrStack.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));
```

Here is your working [code](http://codepen.io/karthikrp/pen/aNbJYv?editors=1010).

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @karthik-rp

or using [Array#slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
arrStack.push(arr.map(function(e) {
    return e.slice();
}));
```